# Tsung replace characters in a dynamic variable

Tags: erlang, tsung

Using

```
 <dyn_variable name="OK_Button" jsonpath="test.items[0].links[0].href"/>
```

I am able to extract the the below url from the json
 `http://localhost:8081/mycode/1.5.0/extended/call/action`

But, In the next request Iwant to make use of the above url by changing the IP and port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example:

```
<dyn_variable name="ok_button" jsonpath = "test.items[0].links[0].href"/>
<setdynvars sourcetype="eval"
        code='fun({Pid,DynVars})->
                  {ok,Val}=ts_dynvars:lookup(ok_button,DynVars),
                  L1 = re:replace(Val,"localhost","192.169.1.100",[{return,list}]),
                  L2 = re:replace(L1,"8801","8800",[{return,list}]),
                  L2 end.'>
    <var name="new_address" />
</setdynvars>

%% ok_button tolower
%% L2 = "http://192.169.1.100:8800/mycode/1.5.0/extended/call/action"

<request subst="true">
     <http url="%%_new_address%%" method="POST" contents="......."
</request>
```